# Returning multiple values asynchronously

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have the requirement of computing these two independent tasks.Earlier I was doing it serially like:

```
string firstHash = CalculateMD5Hash("MyName");
string secondHash = CalculateMD5Hash("NoName");
```

And the method `calculateMD5Hash` looks like.It is used to calculate MD5 hash values for files as big as 16GB:

```
private string CalculateMD5(string filename)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
        }
    }
}
```

But since these 2 `CalculateMD5Hash` methods can run in parallel, I was trying this:

```
Task<string> sequenceFileMd5Task = CalculateMD5("MyName");
Task<string> targetFileMD5task = CalculateMD5("NoName");
string firstHash = await sequenceFileMd5Task;
string secondHash = await targetFileMD5task;
```

And my `CalculateMD5` method looks like:

```
private async Task<string> CalculateMD5(string filename)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
        }
    }
}
```

I hoped for the code to work asynchronously, but it works synchronously.

Comment: A method is asynchronous when it returns an incomplete `Task`. The task returned by the `CalculateMD5` method is always completed, because there is no `await` inside this method, so it runs from start to end synchronously. For a truly asynchronous `GetHashAsync` look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133618/asynchronous-sha256-hashing). Btw according to the [guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) the method `CalculateMD5` should be named `CalculateMD5Async`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to speed this up is to use double-buffering so that one thread can be reading from the file into one buffer, while the MD5 is being calculated for another buffer.

This allows you to overlap the I/O with the computation.

The best way to do this would be to have a single task that was responsible for calculating the Md5 for all the blocks of data, but since that complicates the code quite a bit (and is not likely to yield much better results) I shall instead create a new task for each block.

The code looks like this:

```
public static async Task<byte[]> ComputeMd5Async(string filename)
{
    using (var md5  = MD5.Create())
    using (var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 16384, FileOptions.SequentialScan | FileOptions.Asynchronous))
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024 * 1024; // Adjust buffer size to taste.

        byte[] buffer1 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        byte[] buffer  = buffer1; // Double-buffered, so use 'buffer' to switch between buffers.

        var task = Task.CompletedTask;

        while (true)
        {
            buffer = (buffer == buffer1) ? buffer2 : buffer1; // Swap buffers for double-buffering.
            int n = await file.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            await task;
            task.Dispose();

            if (n == 0)
                break;

            var block = buffer;
            task = Task.Run(() => md5.TransformBlock(block, 0, n, null, 0));
        }

        md5.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 0);

        return md5.Hash;
    }
}
```

Here's a compilable test app:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            string file = @"C:\ISO\063-2495-00-Rev 1.iso";

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) // Try several times.
            {
                sw.Restart();

                var hash = await ComputeMd5Async(file);

                Console.WriteLine("ComputeMd5Async() Took " + sw.Elapsed);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", hash));
                Console.WriteLine();

                sw.Restart();

                hash = ComputeMd5(file);

                Console.WriteLine("ComputeMd5() Took " + sw.Elapsed);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", hash));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public static byte[] ComputeMd5(string filename)
        {
            using var md5    = MD5.Create();
            using var stream = File.OpenRead(filename);

            md5.ComputeHash(stream);

            return md5.Hash;
        }

        public static async Task<byte[]> ComputeMd5Async(string filename)
        {
            using (var md5  = MD5.Create())
            using (var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 16384, FileOptions.SequentialScan | FileOptions.Asynchronous))
            {
                const int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024 * 1024; // Adjust buffer size to taste.

                byte[] buffer1 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                byte[] buffer2 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                byte[] buffer  = buffer1; // Double-buffered, so use 'buffer' to switch between buffers.

                var task = Task.CompletedTask;

                while (true)
                {
                    buffer = (buffer == buffer1) ? buffer2 : buffer1; // Swap buffers for double-buffering.
                    int n = await file.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    await task;
                    task.Dispose();

                    if (n == 0)
                        break;

                    var block = buffer;
                    task = Task.Run(() => md5.TransformBlock(block, 0, n, null, 0));
                }

                md5.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 0);

                return md5.Hash;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the results I got for a file of size ~2.5GB:

```
ComputeMd5Async() Took 00:00:04.8066365
49, 54, 154, 19, 115, 198, 28, 163, 5, 182, 183, 91, 2, 5, 241, 253

ComputeMd5() Took 00:00:06.9654982
49, 54, 154, 19, 115, 198, 28, 163, 5, 182, 183, 91, 2, 5, 241, 253

ComputeMd5Async() Took 00:00:04.7018911
49, 54, 154, 19, 115, 198, 28, 163, 5, 182, 183, 91, 2, 5, 241, 253

ComputeMd5() Took 00:00:07.3552470
49, 54, 154, 19, 115, 198, 28, 163, 5, 182, 183, 91, 2, 5, 241, 253

ComputeMd5Async() Took 00:00:04.6536709
49, 54, 154, 19, 115, 198, 28, 163, 5, 182, 183, 91, 2, 5, 241, 253

ComputeMd5() Took 00:00:06.9807878
49, 54, 154, 19, 115, 198, 28, 163, 5, 182, 183, 91, 2, 5, 241, 253

ComputeMd5Async() Took 00:00:04.7271215
49, 54, 154, 19, 115, 198, 28, 163, 5, 182, 183, 91, 2, 5, 241, 253

ComputeMd5() Took 00:00:07.4089941
49, 54, 154, 19, 115, 198, 28, 163, 5, 182, 183, 91, 2, 5, 241, 253
```

So the async double-buffered version runs about 50% faster.

There may be faster ways, but this is a fairly simple approach.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely to be I/O limited, so parallelising it will probably not speed things up much (and indeed might even slow things down).

Having said that, the issue with your code is that you are not creating any new tasks to run the code in the background (just specifying `async` doesn't create any threads).

Rather than trying to "force" it to use async, the easiest solution is probably to leverage [PLinq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq) via [`AsParallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel?view=netframework-4.8):

```
List<string> files = new List<string>()
{
    "MyName",
    "NoName"
};

var results = files.AsParallel().Select(CalculateMD5).ToList();
```

If you want to restrict the number of threads used for this you can use `WithDegreeOfParallelism()` as per the example below, which restricts the number of parallel threads to 2:

```
var results = files.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(2).Select(CalculateMD5).ToList();
```

Note, however, that if there was such a thing as `MD5.COmputeHashAsync()` you would certainly want to use that along with `async/await` and `Task.WhenAll()` - but such a thing does not exist.

Comment: I tried : files.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(2).Select(CalculateMD5).ToList().But the problem is I have 17 GB file with file name "MyName" and 17GB file with file name "NoName".With the solution provided,it takes approximately 7 minutes ,whereas when I was calculating Hash Values serially,it was taking around 5 minutes.So,in a way performance is not getting improved byfiles.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(2).Select(CalculateMD5).ToList()

Comment: This is not I/O limited.I have a list of List<string> files predefined.

Comment: @user11708636 `This is not I/O limited.I have a list of List<string> files predefined.` But you are reading the data from disk using `File.OpenRead(filename)` which is doing I/O. Since the files are 17GB each, you would need at least 34GB of RAM if you are holding the data in memory... It *is* I/O bound, and the fact that it gets slower when reading the files simultaneously is a result of that.

Comment: since I have RAM of 32GB .1)Is it so that parallel programming will take more time than serial programming because of insufficient RAM?2)so will it be better to run this 2 tasks sequentially rather than parallely?

Comment: @user11708636 In this specific case, yes: Because it is I/O bound it's faster to process the files sequentially since trying to read two files simultaneously slows it down. It is possible to speed this up if you can read chunks from a file and have different chunks being processed by different threads - but you can't do that with `MD5.ComputeHash()`. Note that reading the files simultaneously *may* be faster in some cases, e.g. if the files are on two different hard drives or if they are on an SSD.

Comment: **Note that reading the files simultaneously may be faster in some cases **. But since processing is using RAM  of 32 GB,so will not I/O problem still continue,but to a slight lesser extent?.In that case also ,won't serial programming give better results than parallel programming?

Comment: @user11708636 The processing isn't using 32G of ram - the file is processed in chunks. You would only need all that ram if you read each file into memory entirely before processing it. However, you can read the file in one thread and process it in a separate thread. I'll post that approach as a separate answer in a minute or two.

Answer (score 2):

You may change function body into task then wait for result.

```
private async Task<string> CalculateMD5(string filename)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
            {
                var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
            }
        }
    });
}
```