# SHA256 hash with CancellationToken

Tags: c#, asynchronous, hash, sha256

I need a SHA256 hash function for large files that I can run in the background. I want to have the possibility to cancel the execution (I think with a CancellationToken). With the library function I did not find a way to cancel the process on request.

```
 private byte[] SHA256_Hash(string fileName) {
        byte[] result = null;
        using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create()) {
            int bufferSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB
            using (var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fileName), bufferSize)) {
                result = sha256.ComputeHash(stream);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this: [Asynchronous SHA256 Hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133618/asynchronous-sha256-hashing). Adding support for cancellation is just a matter of inserting the line `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` inside the loop.